# MINGW64 is opening outside of my Console2

Tags: git, mingw-w64, console2

I am using console2 and would like to create a MINGW64 tab. I created a new tab in settings and added the shell directory. However, when I go to open that tab the git-cmd opens up in a seperate window (as if I just ran it normally) and Console2 is frozen until I close git-cmd. I don't think that the file path to the shell is wrong since when I have done that in the past the tab will throw an error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the exact same issue, turns out that I was trying to use Git and Git Bash 64-Bit with Console2 32-Bit. The issue was resolved by going 64-Bit with both.

Comment: A 64bit version of console 2 can be found here: http://www.afterdawn.com/software/system_tools/misc_system_tools/console_64.cfm